# How to inject a singleton in a custom class constructor and use it | .NET Core 2

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have no extensive experience in testing, but I'm setting up a Singleton instance injection for a class I created. However, I don't know how to call that class.  If I do call, I need constructors. If I create an additional empty constructor, the dependencies will appear as null.

I have spent a few days looking for it in the documentation, but it only shows examples of how to inject.  I cannot find how to instantiate the class afterwards.

Also, I see some examples, but many of them are using MVC Controllers, which are instantiated automatically by the framework.

```
Connector.cs
public class Connector
{
    private IConfiguration _configuration;
    public Connector(IConfiguration configuration) {
       _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public Connector() {
    } 

    public string DoSomething() {
      //return Something related to _configuration
    }
}

startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{    
    //Other default config

     services.AddSingleton(new Connector(Configuration));
 }

 HomeController.cs
 public IActionResult Index()
 {

        var x = (new Connector()).DoSomething(); //This will fail as _configuration is not injected
        return View();
 }
```

How can I call Connector with the injected Configuration? Am I missing any dependency resolving?  Am I calling the class incorrectly?

I hope somebody can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behing DI container is that you don't need to handle object creation in your methods. Your `HomeController` also doesn't need to know if `Connector` is actually a singleton or not.

You just inject the dependency to your constructor.
Since you have configured it to be a singleton, DI container will resolve `Connector` to the same instance every time.

```
public class HomeController 
{ 
    private readonly Connector _connector;

    public HomeController(Connector connector)
    {
        _connector = connector;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var x = _connector.DoSomething();
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: I see, so there is no way to inject dependencies into custom classes?

Comment: @PaulArthurWeinberger What do you mean by custom classes? :)

Comment: For example: if i would like to run a Console Application and inject Connector class into a Helper class.

Comment: @PaulArthurWeinberger The code you have provided is ASP.NET Core code, which has its own built-in Dependency Injection container, which is already enabled and all you need to do is to register your dependencies in `ConfigureServices` of `Startup` class. If you want to run a console application (which is not an ASP.NET Core app) and use DI, you will have to create, configure and use DI container yourself. You can probably use the same DI container, which is used in ASP.NET Core (I am not sure), or you can use 3rd party tools like NInject, Autofac, Unity etc.